# Getting absolutely positioned unknown height children to resize the parent on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

## https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/MxazRE

I have a slideshow that the user changes which slide to look at by swiping their mouse cursor horizontally over the slide container.

Because the children (slides) are absolutely positioned I need to dynamically update the height of the parent (slideshow container). Otherwise

Because I dont know the height of the individual slides I need to calculate the tallest div and give that to the parent

Code below to get tallest element below:

```
    function getTallestSegment(element) {
      let elementsHeight = [];
      let height = 0;
      element.forEach(child => {
        elementsHeight.push(child.scrollHeight);
      });
      height = Math.max(...elementsHeight);
      return height;
    }
```

And the window resize snippet to update the parent height dynamically.

```
    window.onresize = function(e){
      Object.assign(item.style, {
        height: getTallestSegment(getChildren) + "px"
      });
    };
```

Now it works, but only only when I downsize the window:
Please have a look in the gif. Notice the height value in the bottom right corner is in fact changing. But only when I downsize the window, **I want it to work when I expand the window width as well!**

Any takers to figure out to make the parent resize in both directions?

Thanks!

[image: gif of problem]

Comment: Are you allowed to use CSS grids? you can have the 3 elements on the same grid cell, they overlap and you can make the height of the row the max-content and you don't even need javascript or absolute positioning

Comment: Check this using the grid https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLPLpv

Comment: Anything is allowed. That could work!

Comment: Ok I'll add an answer with the code and some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, when you expend the viewport, the elements are 100% height of it's container. When you expand, the elements are still 100% height of it's container because the container has a fixed height, that's whay it doesn't shrink.

But with CSS grids you can overlap elements and still make the container resize according to the tallest of them, no need for absolute position and no need for javascript to resize them.

First you make the container a grid:

```
.hover-slide {
  display:grid;
}
```

Then, you put all elements on the same row and column (no need for absolute, left, right, width, height, etc):

```
.hover-slide > * {     
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

And that's it, you can change the active element, but the height will just be the minimal to get all the elements inside.

Your code but using this idea https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLPLpv (I've added a border to see the container's height easily)

Comment: This is brilliant, there are long discussions around how to get parents with absolute children to adapt to their height. Havent seen this solution before

Comment: CSS grids are relativelly new, when I asked if you were allowed to use them I meant that maybe you have some restrictions on browsers support, you may need to implement some kind of fallback if you have to support older browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=grid 87% of support is actually really good though.